# How to bind a control to an element of a XmlDocument in the ViewModel (MVVM Pattern)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, xmldocument

I'm trying to bind a **TextBlock** to an element of a XML document, it works fine if the source is a StaticResouce, but I cannot figure out the syntax to bind to the same XML document when exposed through ViewModel.

Here's the XML document:

```
<Books>
    <Book ID="1" Name="ABC" />
    <Book ID="2" Name="DEF" />
    <Book ID="3" Name="XYZ" />
</Books>
```

**Binding to a StaticResource = SUCCESSFUL**

The resource file contains a XmlDataProvider with reference to Books.xml:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="data" Source="Books.xml"/>
```

And here's how I'm binding to the xml file.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource data},XPath=/Books/Book/@Name}"/>
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="data" Source="../Views/Data.xml" />
```

As I said before, the binding above works fine and it displays "ABC". However, that XmlDocument is supposed to come from SQL Server and exposed through ViewModel (MVVM Pattern).

**Binding to ViewModel = FAILED**

The Books property from the ViewModel is populated with the exactly same XML (see above):

```
public XmlDocument Books { get; set; }
```

And here's the syntax that I'm using to bind to ViewModel:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Books,XPath=/Books/Book/@Name}" />
```

It doesn't return anything and I'm getting the following error message:

> BindingExpression with XPath cannot bind to non-XML object.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on another discussion board. Here's how to bind the control to the XMLDocument property in the ViewModel.

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Books}" Text="{Binding XPath=/Books/Book/@Name}"/>
```

Now I can successfully bind to the XML results coming from SQL Server. Hope that help others with a similar problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In your example where you bind to a StaticResource, your Binding Path points to an XmlDataProvider which 'adapts' your XmlDocument. Whereas in your ViewModel example, your Path is the XmlDocument itself. To achieve an equivalent binding from your ViewModel, the property needs to expose a XmlDataProvider.

Answer (score 1):

ColinE has completely answered the question. But the other solution consists in exposing property BookName.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(XDocument doc)
    {
        this.Document = doc;
    }

    private XDocument Document
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string BookName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Document
                       .Element("Books")
                       .Element("Book")
                       .Attribute("Name").Value;
        }
    }
```

Then you should bind directly to Name property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding BookName}" />
```

Comment: +1 Good idea ... not the answer to the question, but a better approach IMO

Comment: I simplified the example above to make it easier to explain the problem. In reality, there are a few dozen fields in each row, and it wouldn't be feasible to expose each field. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you binding to a source in code-behind, you don't need to use XPath. Simple Path will do.

Code-behind

```
this.DataContext = Books;
```

Xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
```